# Calibrate internal camera under Windows

Tags: software-recommendation, windows, camera

My internal camera (shown as USB 2.0 camera, but it is mounted in the laptop screen) shows all pictures quite blueish in different lighting situations. Manual post processing of photos/videos greatly improves the result. Does somebody know a possibility to calibrate (hue, lightness, contrast, etc.) the camera so that it produces more useful pictures for any application? There is no camera driver from Sony (I have an SVS1511), it uses the generic one from Windows. However I did not find a way to calibrate with the Windows driver. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure this is going to be entirely up to either your camera driver or the software you are using.  You might have better luck on superuser as this is really more of a computer system's question than an audio/visual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found a solution. Not sure if there is a hidden function under Windows to do the calibration, but some programs like Skype can be used to configure the camera settings. Whatever settings are applied in Skype->Options->Video Settings, they are global for the overall system.